# Get shipping methods using API

Tags: magento-1.8, shipping-methods, web-services

I'm trying to make a WebService, getting in argument shoppingCartId and storeId, to return all shipping method available. I'm also using the Owebia shipping extension.

But my problem is here, I have able 5 shipping methos (flatrate, free, owebia 1/2/3), but I only get the flat and free when I use `cart_shipping.list` like it :
`$resultShippingMethods=$proxy>call($sessionId,"cart_shipping.list",array($shoppingCartId));`

So my question is, how can I get magento's default shipping method and also Owebia methods ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `cart_shipping.list` it  Allows you to retrieve the list of available shipping methods for a shopping cart (quote).

your Requirement is that you have to fetch all active shipping method available in that store.

Then you One Solution I have found that

**Step 1:** you can create your custom API to fetch the All `active shipping method.`

**Step 2:** To create a new API you can follow the steps which are giving my Magento it self [link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/create_your_own_api.html)

**Step 3:**  In your API method `getActiveShippingMethods()` type below code.

```
public function getActiveShippingMethods()
{
    $methods = array(array('value'=>'','label'=>Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('--Please Select--')));

    $activeCarriers = Mage::getSingleton('shipping/config')->getActiveCarriers();
    foreach($activeCarriers as $carrierCode => $carrierModel)
    {
       $options = array();
       if( $carrierMethods = $carrierModel->getAllowedMethods() )
       {
           foreach ($carrierMethods as $methodCode => $method)
           {
                $code= $carrierCode.'_'.$methodCode;
                $options[]=array('value'=>$code,'label'=>$method);

           }
           $carrierTitle = Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/'.$carrierCode.'/title');

       }
        $methods[]=array('value'=>$options,'label'=>$carrierTitle);
    }
    return $methods;
}
```

**Step 4 :** Refresh the cache and test the API.

Comment: Thank's, little complicated but usefull =)

Comment: yes some thing is completed but helpful